# How write a dynamic loader that wraps C variadic functions?

Tags: c, variadic-functions, dynamic-loading

In order to avoid depending on a library at run-time I have written a dynamic loader that uses `dlopen` / `dlsym` to load functions form a library at run-time.

To link at build time I use wrapper functions which call into the function pointers set by `dlsym`.

I've run into a problem with variadic functions, where there doesn't seem to be a way to dynamically load the function and have it forward the variadic arguments.

Is there a way to write a wrapper library that supports varargs that doesn't...

- Depend on knowing the number of variadic arguments or ending the arguments with a sentinel value.
- Depend on working around the problem by changing the code which calls into the variadic function (which I happen not to have control over in this case).

It seems like this might be supported but most existing answers suggest to workaround the problem in a way that isn't practical in my use case.

For context the function signature I'm wrapping is:

```
struct wl_proxy *wl_proxy_marshal_flags(
        struct wl_proxy *proxy,
        uint32_t opcode,
        const struct wl_interface *interface,
        uint32_t version,
        uint32_t flags,
        ...);
```

This function is called by generated code (see `wayland-scanner`), although I rather not make this question specifically about Wayland.

---

Note that similar questions have been asked already, such as:

- [How to wrap a variadic function in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70741801)
- [Forward an invocation of a variadic function in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150543)

But they suggest alternatives such as using `vfprintf` which don't work in my use case.

Comment: What is wrong with using a `va_list`?

Comment: Show how you would like to use this. So let's say you want to call either `printf` or `syslog` from a dynamically loaded function. How would the caller know which arguments to pass?

Comment: The function that I'm calling doesn't take a `va_list`.

Comment: @cheatah added the function I'm wrapping.

Comment: I think the links you included lay out all the options that there are.  If none of them work for your application, then you are out of luck.  So this question is really a duplicate.  But for instance, did you see [my answer about `__builtin_apply`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61545790/634919)?

Comment: Some compilers or libraries (e.g. [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/)...) could be helpful. You might also use [GNU lightning](https://www.gnu.org/software/lightning/)

Comment: @nate-eldredge I checked using `__builtin_apply` and it seems that varargs do not work with this.

Comment: So use `wl_proxy_marshal_array_flags`.

Comment: @KamilCuk the code generated by wayland-scanner uses `wl_proxy_marshal_flags`.

Comment: @ideasman42: varargs do work with `__builtin_apply` in general, e.g. the example I included in the post does work for me.  That is one of the main reasons for it to exist.

Comment: @nate-eldredge your right `__builtin_apply` does work (somehow it was failing when I first tried using it). This could be included as an answer.

Comment: In case the variadic arguments are all of the same type, there are some possible macro tricks. (Although using variadic functions is horrible design to begin with, it's such a pointless feature.)

Comment: So something generates C code that calls `wl_proxy_marshal_flags`.  Are you planning to write your own implementation of this function that dlopens the wayland library, dlsyms the real function, and forwards arguments to it?

Answer (score 0):

The usual way is to make the variadic function a mere interface on a real function taking a `va_list` as a parameter. This pattern (which is the way `fprintf` and `vfprintf` work in the Standard Library) provides a smooth way to forward a dynamic number of arguments by calling directly the function using the `va_list`.

Here you could write:

```
struct wl_proxy *vwl_proxy_marshal_flags(
        struct wl_proxy *proxy,
        uint32_t opcode,
        const struct wl_interface *interface,
        uint32_t version,
        uint32_t flags,
        va_list params) {
    // actual code
    ...
}
struct wl_proxy *wl_proxy_marshal_flags(
        struct wl_proxy *proxy,
        uint32_t opcode,
        const struct wl_interface *interface,
        uint32_t version,
        uint32_t flags,
        ...) {
    va_list params
    va_start(params, flags);
    struct wl_proxy *cr = vwl_proxy_marshal_flags(proxy, opcode,
        interface, version, flags, params);
    va_end(params);
    return cr;
}
```

Comment: This relies on being able to modify the `wl_proxy_marshal_flags` function which is in a 3rd party library.

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming all items in the variadic argument list are of the same type*, then you can use this trick:

Implement the actual function as a non-variadic one, taking an array and size. As well as any number of non-variadic arguments. Example:

```c
void actual_func (int this, double that, size_t argc, int argv[argc])
{
  printf("this:%d that:%f\n", this, that);
  for(size_t i=0; i<argc; i++)
    printf("%d ", argv[i]);
}
```

Here `this` and `that` can be any parameters of any type, corresponding to the fixed parameters in your examples. The `argc` and `argv` is the size and array respectively.

We can then write a variadic macro to translate the variadic call into a plain function call:

```
#define COUNT_ARGS(...) ( sizeof((int[]){__VA_ARGS__}) / sizeof(int) )
#define func(this,that,...) actual_func(this, that, COUNT_ARGS(__VA_ARGS__), (int[]){__VA_ARGS__})
```

The helper macro `COUNT_ARGS` counts the number of variadic items - they all have to be `int` or it won't work. This gives the array size. Then a temporary array in the form of a compound literal is initialized with the variadic arguments, then passed to the function. Full example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void actual_func (int this, double that, size_t argc, int argv[argc])
{
  printf("this:%d that:%f\n", this, that);
  for(size_t i=0; i<argc; i++)
    printf("%d ", argv[i]);
}

#define COUNT_ARGS(...) ( sizeof((int[]){__VA_ARGS__}) / sizeof(int) )
#define func(this,that,...) actual_func(this,that,COUNT_ARGS(__VA_ARGS__),(int[]){__VA_ARGS__})

int main (void) 
{
  func(1, 1.0f, 1, 2, 3);
}
```

This has the same type safety as integer assignment, meaning so-so, but it is *way* safer than variadic functions.

Answer (score 0):

Bad news: I don't think there is an universal (platform-independent) solution.

Good news: Wayland's developers seem to have thought of this problem, that's why they created `_array_` functions, e.g. in `wayland-client-core.h`:

```
struct wl_proxy *
wl_proxy_marshal_flags(struct wl_proxy *proxy, uint32_t opcode,
                       const struct wl_interface *interface,
                       uint32_t version,
                       uint32_t flags, ...);

struct wl_proxy *
wl_proxy_marshal_array_flags(struct wl_proxy *proxy, uint32_t opcode,
                             const struct wl_interface *interface,
                             uint32_t version,
                             uint32_t flags,
                             union wl_argument *args);
```

The former function calls the latter:

```
WL_EXPORT struct wl_proxy *
wl_proxy_marshal_flags(struct wl_proxy *proxy, uint32_t opcode,
                       const struct wl_interface *interface, uint32_t version,
                       uint32_t flags, ...)
{
        union wl_argument args[WL_CLOSURE_MAX_ARGS];
        va_list ap;

        va_start(ap, flags);
        wl_argument_from_va_list(proxy->object.interface->methods[opcode].signature,
                                 args, WL_CLOSURE_MAX_ARGS, ap);
        va_end(ap);

        return wl_proxy_marshal_array_flags(proxy, opcode, interface, version, flags, args);
}
```

Comment: An issue with using `wl_proxy_marshal_array_flags` is the calls to `wl_proxy_marshal_flags` are from source files generated by `wayland-scanner`, so the source generator would need to be updated, or some non-trivial post-processing would need to be performed on the source.

Comment: You can try and insert the quoted `wl_proxy_marshal_flags` implementation into your code, replacing                 `wl_proxy_marshal_array_flags` to `(*ptrto_wl_proxy_marshal_array_flags)`